# Downloading Artifacts using build-info in Artifactory

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, artifactory

It makes sense that there will be a way to download all artifacts related to a specific build-name & build-number (using CLI), but I can't seem to find that way. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

1. Simplest would be with:

   jfrog rt dl --build myBuild/5
2. It should be also possible with a file spec:

   jfrog rt dl --spec spec.json

With spec.json:

```
    {
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "*",
            "target": "froggy/",
            "build": "myBuild/5"
        }
     ]
   }
```

See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs
You can also do it with AQL in more advanced cases.